# how to achieve apache camel file component transactional behavior

Tags: transactions

how to achieve transaction behavior with camel file component. Can I use transacted on my route for file.My application runs in JTA/XA environment. I have a requirement to move the contents of a file to database or a websphere MQ queue. Eg I will be polling on a file/folder.My file may have 100 records with some delimiter. I need to route these records to database/MQ queue.I need to commit all 100 records or none. Suppose If some exception occurs after inserting 50 records it should rollback and preserve the file with 100 records. Is it possible to achieve this behavior with file component ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to customize the file component, but it can be done with JBoss's XA Transactional File System: http://narayana.jboss.org/subprojects/fileio

Comment: Thanks for that. If iam using Apache camel file component then what is the impact of "transacted" attribute in a route with file component.